# How to combine mean+sd into a table in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Right now I have the following code for `mean` and `sd` seperated as

```
aggregate(renters$rentm25,
          list(Province = renters$pvreg25, Mean = renters$pvreg25), mean)

aggregate(renters$rentm25,
          list(Province = renters$pvreg25, Mean = renters$pvreg25), sd)
```

Data

[image]

I also want to know how I can change the value of x to name it as mean and sd?

Answer (score 1):

The `doBy` package doesn't get a lot of attention, but it does this job nicely:

```
library(doBy)
summaryBy(rentm25 ~ pvreg25, FUN=c(mean, sd), data=renters)
```

But since you did not provide example data, it is not clear that this is what you are looking for.